# Animiation Drawable ending

Tags: android, animation

I got this animation drawable running, and i want to continue only when it is finished. this code results in overlapping images.

```
public void onClick(View w) {
        rangen = r.nextInt(4-1)+1;
        frameAnimation.start();

        if (rangen==1){
            enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.paper);
            restextj.setText("You Lose!");}
        else if (rangen==2){
            enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.rock);
            restextj.setText("Draw");}
        else if (rangen==3){
            enemyj.setImageResource(R.drawable.sciss);
            restextj.setText("You Win!");}}
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add an animation listener to your frameAnimation before you start it

```
frameAnimation.setAnimationListener( new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation) {
        animation.setAnimationListener(null);
        //do whatever work you need done 
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart (Animation animation) {
    }
});
```